# composer is not updating for laravel command "simplesoftwareio/simple-sms": "1.1.*" after adding in composer.json

Tags: php, json, laravel, command, sms

I want to integrate SMS plugin in my site. I added the command in composer.json `"simplesoftwareio/simple-sms": "1.1.*"` after adding i update the composer, following response is get. I am using Laravel 4.1* version. Please suggest for this one.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.1.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.3
    - Installation request for aeyoll/laravel-free-mobile-notification-sender 1.
* -> satisfiable by aeyoll/laravel-free-mobile-notification-sender[1.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.1
    - aeyoll/laravel-free-mobile-notification-sender 1.0.0 requires illuminate/s
upport 4.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2
.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.1
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.12
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.16
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.17
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.2
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.3
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.4
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.5
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.6
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.7
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.8
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0|don't install illuminate/support v4
.2.9
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel
/framework[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15,
 v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23,
 v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.31,
 v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
```

Comment: What else is in your composer.json file?

Comment: `"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",  
  "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8",
  "simplesoftwareio/simple-sms": "1.1.*"
 },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to your installed laravel version that is 4.1 
To install this package in your project please upgrade your laravel project version from 4.1 to greater version.